# How to set base font size for my npm package

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, font-size

I have 2 main projects, one project is using base font size as 14px and another one is using base font size as 10px. I am using tailwind css inside both main projects. So if I use text-base, text-sm for font size inside main projects, font size depends on rem and rem depends on root font size.

I have created a npm package using rollup, tailwind, react and I am using created library inside my 2 main projects. I would like to use base font size as 16px only in my npm package UI Components. But in the final output, code inside npm package is taking the main project base font size.

Is there any option to use different base font size inside npm package and main project seperately

Comment: u could create a _style.css file were u add the styles that are reused in multiple pages. then u can just import and declare that name in ur css files.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the font size by replacing the default size of `text-base` from 16px to 14px in `tailwind.config.js` file of your project.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontSize: {

      'base': '14px',
 
    }
  }
}
```

More resources [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#customizing-your-theme)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I can't modify in my main project because I have n number of pages in my main project. If I modify in my main project, I need to again reapply new font size due to changes in config file in all screens

Comment: Just make the change in the tailwind config file of your main project

Comment: It will affect my current UI pages.